# R: Text and function in one 'cell'

Tags: r, rstudio

I have to create a table where I analyse 9 variables in a bigger data set. For each variable, I have to state how it is scaled, what the measure of central tendency is, and what the dispersion measure is.

As, depending on how the variable is scaled, I have different measures, I would like to specify that inside the corresponding cell of the table I'm writing. Example:

`"Median: (median(GB$government,na.rm=T)"` 
or
`"Median:" (median(GB$government, na.rm=T)`

This doesn't work, RStudio warns me because of an unexpected symbol. The code I have is this (it includes `specify_decimal` because I have to include two decimals of each value - that function works flawlessly so don't mind it :)

```
MZT <- c("Median:" specify_decimal(median(GB$government,na.rm=T),2),
     specify_decimal(Modus(GB$local),2),specify_decimal(Modus(GB$gender),2),
     specify_decimal(mean(GB$height,na.rm=T),2),
     specify_decimal(mean(GB$weight,na.rm=T),2),specify_decimal(mean(GB$age,na.rm=T),2),
     specify_decimal(mean(GB$education,na.rm=T),2),
     specify_decimal(median(GB$income,na.rm=T),2),
     specify_decimal(median(GB$father_educ,na.rm=T),2))
```

/ edit: I now understand how kable works :D

Comment: It's not parseable, but even more important, it's unclear what data you have and what you are trying to do with this (faulty) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make custom tables in R is to use the `knitr::kable()` function, along with R Markdown. Here is a trivial example that prints a table comparing sample and theoretical values for an exponential distribution where lambda = 0.2.

```
library(knitr)
Statistic <- c("Mean","Std. Deviation")
Sample <- c(round(5.220134,2),round(5.4018713,2))
Theoretical <- c(5.0,5.0)
theTable <- data.frame(Statistic,Sample,Theoretical)
rownames(theTable) <- NULL
kable(theTable)
```

...and the text based output:

```
> kable(theTable)


|Statistic      | Sample| Theoretical|
|:--------------|------:|-----------:|
|Mean           |   5.22|           5|
|Std. Deviation |   5.40|           5|
>
```

When run in R Markdown, the output looks like this:

[image]

### Explanation

I used the following technique to create the table.

1. Data Frame is used as the container to hold the data
2. Each column in the table is a column of data in the data frame
3. The first column stores the names of the rows
4. The second thru n-th columns store different values related to each row